# R, structural change and Wald test

Tags: r, time-series, change-point

I'm doing a time series analysis and wanna identify structural breaks from a regression. Here are the data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramyshaban01/dataframe/aa074811a322b5f5252fcb59c81b75bd6503d260/data.csv here what I have done:

```
library(strucchange)
formula <- as.formula(paste("Variation_pce_shifted ~ Variation_hw +", paste0("hw_lag", 1:4, collapse = " + "), "+", paste0("pce_lag", 1:4, collapse = " + "), "+", paste0("U_gap_lag", 1:4, collapse = " + ")))

breaks <- breakpoints(formula, data=clean_data, h = 15) 

plot(breaks)
breaks2 <- breakpoints(breaks, breaks = 2)
```

the `breakpoints()` command, using a Bayesian criterium, show me I should keep two structural breaks, and so did I. But then I wanna test for the significance of those break points.

I chose to use a Wald test (maybe not the most relevant?). I didn't find any command calculating the Wald statistic for me, so I computed it manually

```
wald_stats <- lapply(breaks2$breakpoints, function(bp) {
  coef_before <- coef(breaks2)[bp, 1]
  coef_after <- coef(breaks2)[bp, 2]
  
  # Calculate the standard error (se)
  coef_after_sd <- sd(coef_after)
  num_obs_after <- sum(breaks2$breakpoints[bp] < row(clean_data))
  se <- coef_after_sd / sqrt(num_obs_after)
wald_stat <- (coef_after - coef_before) / se
```

BTW, please confirm that my formula for the Wald stat is good (I don't know if I should put in the formula the number of observations for the full period or the period after the breakpoint) But then, I don't know how to do the test, I heard that there was a command `wald.test()`, but don't know how to use it. Don't know neither how many degrees of freedom I should subtract from the number of observations, and neither the distribution table (in this case is it normal or chi-square?)

Thank you for your attention.